# Can a working folder belong to both SVN and git repositories?

Tags: git, github, svn

We have a **SVN** repository with many years of revisions and tags for different release builds, but we've been having problems accessing the remote **SVN** at times.

To improve things we are considering just cloning the latest release *v11* to **git**, and using **GitHub** and **HitHub Desktop** to maintain that version onwards, while using **SVN** to maintain all previous releases and the number of remaining outstanding branches for those earlier releases.

My question is, given I have a working folder for *v11* from **SVN** (that has the `.svn` hidden folder), can I point my **git** local repository to the same working folder (thereby adding the hidden `.git` folder), such that if I merged changes via **SVN** to that working folder, I could then merge those changes to **git**?

For example, I might merge a change from a previous release that altered one file. Now my **SVN** working folder shows that it has 1 file that has changed, and I can commit that to the *v11* branch.

If I was then to open **GitHub Desktop**, it would also show that 1 file has changed that I can then commit to the local repository, followed by a push up to **GitHub**.

Eventually we'll be done with prior releases and would work from **git** only.

Does these look like a sensible approach?

Comment: Thinking about this some more, I can see a problem if we make a change in v11 only in git, as that would mean if we were to do a merge from v10 using SVN, it would say that the working folder has uncommitted changes.

Comment: It *can* be done, but I don't recommend doing it for everyday work—it gets very confusing. (I assume you've looked at converting the entire SVN history to Git and have rejected that for some reason. That's what most people seem to do these days though.)

Comment: agreed, just switch to get, push your whole team through it, get your automation switch over, and get it done in a few dedicated days or whatever it takes.  you'll make the productivity back in the first few days or weeks of using git, if you have a decent branching model.

Comment: @torek and "Daniel Farrel". Our original idea was to migrate the entire SVN repository to git, but every attempt so far has failed due to the size of the project (2.2 GB of Delphi source code) and the number of branches we have outstanding (the trunk, which is version 8; version 9, 10 and 11 active branches; and 37 additional branches from either 9, 10 or 11). It doesn't help that the repository is at a remote site and we occasionally get timeouts trying to use it, or it is completely unavailable (which predicated the move to git in the first place).

Comment: If at all possible, do the conversion *on the SVN host*. If necessary, lock the project entirely and then transfer the SVN repository–physically, if necessary, by FedEx-ing a disk copy—to someplace where you can do the conversion.